# Publish a Flex project, which is better option SWF or AIR?

Tags: apache-flex, air, flash

If I made a project with flex, and i want to distribute it, what it´s the better choice? i mean, it is not internet app, just desktop demo, what about the computer where application should be executed, there is any way to pack the application togheter with the flash/AIR player, in order that everything needed will be just in the exe or dmg file?

Comment: how large is the intended audience?

Comment: just few people, but really big bosses, so i dont want to annoy them with cryptic installation manual or so, i just want click&go solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you export it as an air application the clients will need to have air installed.

There is an option to deploy an air 2.0 application as an executable

Answer (score 1):

AIR is cross platform so if you go that route you should only have to generate one deliverable. Otherwise you'll need to make a PC projector and a Mac projector.

Comment: that´s really a good point.
but what about AIR, the user should install something in the computer? or the viewer it comes just embedded in the published project.

Comment: @Ignatius It doesn't come embedded - user should install AIR runtime - just like you need java runtime to run java apps.

Answer (score 0):

click&go solution ? Deploy it online as a Flex app. Using Flash Player, it will be loaded without any problem in any browser. Just give your boss the URL he'll be good to go !

Comment: yes, you are right, problem is that i dont know why, some people doesnt look the same way an aplication that is running inside a browser, somehow they think that is not as professional as desktop application, so i prefear always to provide an executable file.

Answer (score 0):

You can try exporting with a **Captive Runtime**. It creates either folder with the Windows files or an
 .app bundle on Mac. The user will not need to install Adobe AIR or Flash Player to use it. One drawback is that it has to be built on Windows for the window executable, and on a Mac for the .app Mac file.

See [Packaging a captive runtime bundle for desktop computers](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f709e16db131e43659b9-8000.html) from Adobe's site for more information.

I believe you need to be using at least AIR 3.5 to generate an application with the captive runtime for desktop.

If you are using Flash Builder 4.7, there should be an option for exporting with the captive runtime. If you are using Flash Builder 4.6 or less, you can do it through command line with ADT.